# how to calculate rows in MS Access page

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, row

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvIfG.png)

I want to calculate the minimum and maximum number of rows that will fit in one database page for Microsoft Access for each one of the tables in the image, `string` for `customerName` and `orderMessage`, `long integer` for all `ID` and two primary keys, `single` for the `taxrate`, `doubles` for `orderTotal` and `taxableAmount`, and `Boolean` for `taxableFlag`.

The minimum length for the `customerName` and `orderMessage` should be `0` characters for both and maximum length of `71` characters for `customerName` and `255` for `orderMessage`.

Also, is there a page overhead for Microsoft Access (Jet 4)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, such exercises yield unreliable results.  If you are trying to do capacity planning, the best thing to do is create your table and load it up with 1% or 10% of your estimated total, and see how big it is.  You have to consider room for indexes, how many of your rows have null values for some fields, etc.